# iOS 8 UIImagePickerController to take photos only photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am using an `UIImagePickerController` with `sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;`

However I want to specify that I want to take only photos, not videos , (in a native camera user can switch to video) is there a way to do so ?

Here is the code I am using :

```
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO))
    return ;
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose picture or
    // movie capture, if both are available:
    cameraUI.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My 1st guess was is to change the `sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;` but the other options are galleries options.

My 2nd guess is: to change the array of `mediaTypes` but I don't know to which 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimagepickercontroller_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode

```
cameraUI.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
```

Comment: Thank you very much -> worked like a charm (I just wasn't looking in the right place) 
(I will accept the answer in 5 minutes).

Comment: I am sorry to be annoying but how can i specify to take only photos from gallery ?

Comment: A better answer to the question would be to change how the OP is setting the `mediaTypes` value. Instead of specifying "all available", specify `kUTTypeImage` as described in the docs for the `mediaTypes` property.

Comment: @user3351949 To use the photo library, take a few minutes to read the docs for `UIImagePickerController`. It tells you how to do what you want. SO is not a replacement for reading the docs first.